# No audio for WEBM format

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, youtube-dl, yt-dlp

I'm trying to download a video because I don't like the forced HDR by YouTube. I got the following output when entering this command `yt-dlp -F "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19h1iUcC3QU"`

```
ID  EXT   RESOLUTION FPS HDR CH │   FILESIZE    TBR PROTO │ VCODEC         VBR ACODEC      ABR ASR MORE INFO
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
sb2 mhtml 48x27        0        │                   mhtml │ images                                 storyboard
sb1 mhtml 80x45        0        │                   mhtml │ images                                 storyboard
sb0 mhtml 160x90       0        │                   mhtml │ images                                 storyboard
599 m4a   audio only          2 │    3.15MiB    31k https │ audio only         mp4a.40.5   31k 22k ultralow, m4a_dash
600 webm  audio only          2 │    3.41MiB    33k https │ audio only         opus        33k 48k ultralow, webm_dash
139 m4a   audio only          2 │    4.99MiB    49k https │ audio only         mp4a.40.5   49k 22k low, m4a_dash
249 webm  audio only          2 │    5.04MiB    49k https │ audio only         opus        49k 48k low, webm_dash
250 webm  audio only          2 │    6.70MiB    65k https │ audio only         opus        65k 48k low, webm_dash
140 m4a   audio only          2 │   13.25MiB   129k https │ audio only         mp4a.40.2  129k 44k medium, m4a_dash
251 webm  audio only          2 │   13.26MiB   130k https │ audio only         opus       130k 48k medium, webm_dash
17  3gp   176x144      8      1 │    7.72MiB    75k https │ mp4v.20.3      75k mp4a.40.2    0k 22k 144p
597 mp4   256x144     15        │    3.38MiB    33k https │ avc1.4d400b    33k video only          144p, mp4_dash
598 webm  256x144     15        │    2.84MiB    28k https │ vp9            28k video only          144p, webm_dash
160 mp4   256x144     30        │    9.88MiB    97k https │ avc1.4d400c    97k video only          144p, mp4_dash
278 webm  256x144     30        │    9.13MiB    89k https │ vp9            89k video only          144p, webm_dash
330 webm  256x144     60 10     │   23.77MiB   232k https │ vp9.2         232k video only          144p60 HDR, webm_dash
133 mp4   426x240     30        │   22.59MiB   221k https │ avc1.4d4015   221k video only          240p, mp4_dash
242 webm  426x240     30        │   19.64MiB   192k https │ vp9           192k video only          240p, webm_dash
331 webm  426x240     60 10     │   49.09MiB   480k https │ vp9.2         480k video only          240p60 HDR, webm_dash
134 mp4   640x360     30        │   55.16MiB   539k https │ avc1.4d401e   539k video only          360p, mp4_dash
18  mp4   640x360     30      2 │   76.83MiB   751k https │ avc1.42001E   751k mp4a.40.2    0k 44k 360p
243 webm  640x360     30        │   43.72MiB   427k https │ vp9           427k video only          360p, webm_dash
332 webm  640x360     60 10     │  105.55MiB  1032k https │ vp9.2        1032k video only          360p60 HDR, webm_dash
135 mp4   854x480     30        │   96.85MiB   947k https │ avc1.4d401f   947k video only          480p, mp4_dash
244 webm  854x480     30        │   78.74MiB   770k https │ vp9           770k video only          480p, webm_dash
333 webm  854x480     60 10     │  198.97MiB  1945k https │ vp9.2        1945k video only          480p60 HDR, webm_dash
22  mp4   1280x720    30      2 │ ~243.90MiB  2329k https │ avc1.64001F  2329k mp4a.40.2    0k 44k 720p
136 mp4   1280x720    30        │  225.09MiB  2200k https │ avc1.4d401f  2200k video only          720p, mp4_dash
247 webm  1280x720    30        │  143.60MiB  1403k https │ vp9          1403k video only          720p, webm_dash
298 mp4   1280x720    60        │  344.79MiB  3370k https │ avc1.4d4020  3370k video only          720p60, mp4_dash
302 webm  1280x720    60        │  246.15MiB  2406k https │ vp9          2406k video only          720p60, webm_dash
334 webm  1280x720    60 10     │  454.25MiB  4439k https │ vp9.2        4439k video only          720p60 HDR, webm_dash
299 mp4   1920x1080   60        │  583.68MiB  5704k https │ avc1.64002a  5704k video only          1080p60, mp4_dash
303 webm  1920x1080   60        │  379.11MiB  3705k https │ vp9          3705k video only          1080p60, webm_dash
335 webm  1920x1080   60 10     │  695.69MiB  6799k https │ vp9.2        6799k video only          1080p60 HDR, webm_dash
308 webm  2560x1440   60        │    1.30GiB 13055k https │ vp9         13055k video only          1440p60, webm_dash
336 webm  2560x1440   60 10     │    1.63GiB 16332k https │ vp9.2       16332k video only          1440p60 HDR, webm_dash
315 webm  3840x2160   60        │    2.64GiB 26395k https │ vp9         26395k video only          2160p60, webm_dash
337 webm  3840x2160   60 10     │    2.91GiB 29139k https │ vp9.2       29139k video only          2160p60 HDR, webm_dash
```

I want to download the 308 format (1440p without HDR).
I can read on the line "video only", but the last available has a bad quality (720p), so It doesn't interest me. My final command is `yt-dlp -f 308 --merge-output-format --remux-video mp4 "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19h1iUcC3QU"`

I tried to use `--merge-output` option and `--remux-video mp4` to convert in mp4 if needed to get the audio but It doesn't seems to work...

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: This is really the type of task you should use JDownloader for. Just pick the version you want from a list - https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNC9M.jpg

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm on macOS. Guess, I'll wait the week end for meet up my Windows PC again (and on Apple Silicon so getting a functional Windows is a pain). By any chance, does this piece of software gives the command it uses?

Comment: It's cross-platform, that pic was taken on a Mac (look at the title bar;) It's open-source, so I guess you could look it up. https://jdownloader.org

Comment: @Tetsujin *Facepalm* You're right, well, I'll try that until I found a command working. Thanks!

Comment: @BlindSpots It's the perfect answer, I didn't know I could sum video and audio ID. Would you like to post your answer, and I mark it as such?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

###### Choose Specific Video & Audio stream for download

- **yt-dlp** allows you to download one or more formats by **ID**
- a format might contain **audio *and* video**, or **audio *only*** or **video *only***
- if you choose formats that can coexist in the same container, **yt-dlp** will mux them for you **by default** following download

You chose **ID 308**, a video only stream in a **webm container**.  **ID 251** would complement that as it is an **opus** audio only stream also in a **webm container**.

| ID | EXT | Resolution | FPS | CH | FILESIZE | TBR | PROTO | VCODEC | VBR | ACODEC | MORE INFO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 308 | webm | 2560x1440 | 60 |  | 1.30GiB | 13055k | https | vp9 | 13055k | video only | 1440p60, webm_dash |
| 251 | webm | audio only |  | 2 | 13.26MiB | 130k | https | audio only |  | opus | 130k 48k medium, webm_dash |

To combine the two formats simply include them both delimited by a `+` following your `-f` switch

```
yt-dlp -f 308+251 "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19h1iUcC3QU"
```